# Having Trouble Forming Mathematical Proof

Tags: proof-writing

I'm having trouble forming a mathematical proof for a question. I can write down thousands of examples with various values of `n` that shows it's correct, but I'm not sure how to turn that into a mathematical proof it when multiple functions are involved.

$f_{1}, f_{2}$ and $f_{3}$ are functions on positive real numbers. Prove that if $f_{1}(n) \in O(f_{2}(n))$ and $f_{2}(n) \in O(f_{3}(n))$ then $f_{1}(n) \times f_{2}(n) \in O(f_{3}(n)^{2})$

Comment: You should write down what each of the three statements means, it may become obvious to you if you look at them together.

Comment: Expand out the definition of big-O notation and convert the big-O statements to inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{cases}\left|\frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}\right|\le M_1\\{}\\\left|\frac{f_2(n)}{f_3(n)}\right|\le M_2\end{cases}\;\;\implies \left|\frac{f_1(n)f_2(n)}{f_3(n)^2}\right|=\left|\frac{f_1(n)}{f_3(n)}\right|\left|\frac{f_2(n)}{f_3(n)}\right|\le \ldots\ldots?$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm still completely lost. My highest education is high school but I've read a bit about mathematical induction and could do the simpler examples from the mathematical induction page. Could you explain each of the steps for this answer so I can follow through? Right now I'm kinda lost. Why are we dividing f1 / f2? What is M1 and M2? How do we handle the "is in" sign instead of the equals sign? Sorry about having all these questions :(

Comment: @Yuki, do you know what $\;f=\mathcal O(g)\;$ means? If you don't then we're talking nonsense here. Perhaps you should first google "big O notation" and then come back.

Comment: I do! I can reason about and give complexities for algorithms, but I have issues working through proofs (as above).

Comment: @Yuki But then I can't understand why you ask about $\;M_1,M_2\;$, the division and stuff...! Please do write what is your definition of $\;f=\mathcal O(g)\;$ ...

Comment: Spent a while trying to understand it, and I kind of have it. I guess my question right now is how does http://puu.sh/7GgDK/cf17606602.png? Shouldn't they both by divided by $f_{3}$? Also, what should we put on the right hand side of the equality? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, that was a typo: both are divided by $\;f_3\;$ in the right side.

Comment: Okay, that's awesome! I'm understanding it a bit better now. Would $f_{3}(n)^2$ go on the other side of the equality where you have the dots?

Comment: @Yuki: perhaps if you noted that $$\left|\frac{f_1(n)}{f_3(n)}\right| =\left|\frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}\right|\left|\frac{f_2(n)}{f_3(n)}\right|$$ so that $$\left|\frac{f_1(n)f_2(n)}{f_3(n)^2}\right| =\left|\frac{f_1(n)}{f_2(n)}\right|\left|\frac{f_2(n)}{f_3(n)}\right| \times\left|\frac{f_2(n)}{f_3(n)}\right|$$ things might be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So we have three functions, all of them defined (and positive, for simplicity) for sufficiently large $x\in{\mathbb R}$.

The statement $f_1(x)=O\bigl(f_2(x)\bigr)$ means the follwing: There is a $C_1$ and an $x_1$ such that

$$f_1(x)\leq C_1 f_2(x)\qquad(x>x_1)\ .$$
Similarly, $f_2(x)=O\bigl(f_3(x)\bigr)$ means that there is a $C_2$ and an $x_2$ such that
$$f_2(x)\leq C_2 f_3(x)\qquad(x>x_2)\ .$$
Then for $x>\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ we have
$$f_1(x)\>f_2(x)\leq C_1 f_2(x)\cdot C_2f_3(x)\leq C_1C_2 f_3(x)\cdot C_2 f_3(x)=C\bigr(f_3(x)\bigr)^2$$
with $C:=C_1C_2^2$. This proves the claim.